# Cloud function fails after changing Runtime to Node.js 10

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to take firebase backup through a cloud function. The function was running completely fine when I was using Runtime: Node.js 8. However, since it is going to be deprecated soon, I now have to use Node.js 10. My fcloud function now fails with the below error:

Error: function execution failed. Details:
Cannot read property 'charCodeAt' of undefined

Detailed error log:

```
2020-05-27 11:01:21.820 IST
firestore_export
8kxlp9s867dy
TypeError: Cannot read property 'charCodeAt' of undefined at peg$parsetemplate (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/pathTemplateParser.js:304:17) at Object.peg$parse [as parse] (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/pathTemplateParser.js:633:18) at new PathTemplate (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/pathTemplate.js:55:54) at segments.forEach.segment (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/pathTemplate.js:120:29) at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) at PathTemplate.render (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/pathTemplate.js:114:23) at FirestoreAdminClient.databasePath (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1/firestore_admin_client.js:904:57) at exports.scheduledFirestoreBackup (/workspace/index.js:6:31) at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:330:28) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Expand all | Collapse all
{
 insertId: "000000-f688386c-8f2b-4146-aaf7-1fe67c656fa2"  

labels: {…}  
 logName: "projects/firestore-249705/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-05-27T05:31:31.171084310Z"  

resource: {…}  
 severity: "ERROR"  
 textPayload: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'charCodeAt' of undefined
    at peg$parsetemplate (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/pathTemplateParser.js:304:17)
    at Object.peg$parse [as parse] (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/pathTemplateParser.js:633:18)
    at new PathTemplate (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/pathTemplate.js:55:54)
    at segments.forEach.segment (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/pathTemplate.js:120:29)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at PathTemplate.render (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/pathTemplate.js:114:23)
    at FirestoreAdminClient.databasePath (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1/firestore_admin_client.js:904:57)
    at exports.scheduledFirestoreBackup (/workspace/index.js:6:31)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:330:28)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)"  
 timestamp: "2020-05-27T05:31:21.820Z"  
 trace: "projects/firestore-249705/traces/74e27700d135763bc4e7892ebb1a2333"  
}
```

My index.js is as below:

```
const firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const client = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();
// Replace BUCKET_NAME
const bucket = 'gs://gcp_firestore_ae2/firestore_export'
exports.scheduledFirestoreBackup = (event, context) => {
  const databaseName = client.databasePath(
    process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
    '(default)'
  );
return client
    .exportDocuments({
      name: databaseName,
      outputUriPrefix: bucket,
      // Leave collectionIds empty to export all collections
      // or define a list of collection IDs:
      // collectionIds: ['users', 'posts']
      collectionIds: ['most_valuable_items','nric_img','pay_slip','pic_of_ofc_entrance'],
    })
    .then(responses => {
      const response = responses[0];
      console.log(`Operation Name: ${response['name']}`);
      return response;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the full error, and help us determine which line of code it's referring to here.

Comment: Added the detailed error log @Doug Stevenson

Comment: @google-cloud/firestore - what version is used?

Comment: 8.3.0 is the version @Sergey Reus

Comment: May [this github issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-automl/issues/107) be related?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same issue.  I fixed it by changing:

`process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT`

to my actual Project ID (e.g. "my_app_37274")

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, It seems like in previous versions we don't need to **GCLOUD_PROJECT** in environment variable i.e it automatically detects it, but from node 10 onwards we need to pass this explicitly.
That's how I resolved it.
So instead of hardcoding it, try passing **GCLOUD_PROJECT** in cloud functions environment variables.

Note: **GCLOUD_PROJECT** is project id, not the project name.